# Insufficient Permissions error

Tags: c#, google-prediction

I'm trying to write a console app to use Google Prediction.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I keep getting "Insufficient Permissions". How can I fix this.  How can one see what request is actually being generated?

```
    //Desired Request:  GET https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/1043149216958/trainedmodels/list?               
    //                      pageToken=%22%22&maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

    public async Task Run() 
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("Aggreate Volume 1 Client Secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] {PredictionService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl}, 
                "user", CancellationToken.None );
        }

        var service =
            new PredictionService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Aggregate Volume 2"
                    }
                );

        try 
        {
            var response = service.Trainedmodels.List().Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by making a number of changes.  From the Google Developers Console I got the following information (I chose to make the Project Name and the Product Name the same.  They can be different.):

```
    API:                Prediction API v1.6
    Project Name:       Aggregate Volumes MTFE
    Project ID:         golden-sentry-848
    Project No:         1043149216958
    Product Name:       Aggregate Volumes MTFE
    Predictive Model:   mtfe
```

The API version is very important.  The installed package and the using statements both have to agree.  The package download is

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Prediction.v1_6
```

and the required using statements are:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Prediction.v1_6;
using Google.Apis.Prediction.v1_6.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
```

There are some naming problems that caused me some confusion.  When you initialize the Prediction Services, ApplicationName is the Product Name you specified in Google Developers Console.  The parameter required in service.Trainedmodels.List is the Project No. assigned when you created the project in Google Developers Console.  Here's the code:

```
    public async Task 
    Run() {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("Aggregate Volumes MTFE Client Secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] {PredictionService.Scope.Prediction},
                "user", CancellationToken.None );
            }

        var service =
            new PredictionService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Aggregate Volumes MTFE"
                    }
                );

        try {
            var pre = service.Trainedmodels.List("1043149216958");
            var response = pre.Execute();
            }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you create a new login to answer your own question?

Comment: David, I don't know how I got two logins.  That certainly wasn't my intent.  It took a fair amount of experimentation and work to get the code to function.  My purpose is to give others a starting position that really works.

Comment: That's ok. I reformatted your question to make it look more like regular C# and less like JavaScript, which might have confused some readers.